# Loop Through Specific Sheets In Workbook And Copy/Paste To 1 overall Sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

I have multiple sheets starting with BT, on those sheet there are three table ranges I want to copy and paste to one sheet. There is no exact amount of "BT" sheets.

There are some word in Dutch. Example codename Blad3 is the same as Sheet3. I use this because I want to avoid if someone changes a sheetname that the code no longer works.

I know that I have to delete the select functions, but don't know how to get it working then.

```vb
Sub Overzicht_2()

    Dim ShtNames As Variant: ShtNames = Array("BT")
    Dim LR62 As Long
    Dim LR63 As Long
    Dim LR98 As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wtrws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = LBound(ShtNames) To UBound(ShtNames)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wtrws = wb.Worksheets(ShtNames(i))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not wtrws Is Nothing Then
            'Code 62
            wtrws.Range("B11:V170").Copy
            LR62 = Blad3.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            Range("B" & LR62).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
              xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            
            'Code 63
            wtrws.Range("B176:V205").Copy
            LR63 = Blad3.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            Range("B" & LR63).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
              xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Range("A1").Select
            
            'Code 98
            wtrws.Range("B211:V290").Copy
            LR98 = Blad3.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            Range("B" & LR98).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
              xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Next d
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Blad1.Select
    Range("B3").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few pointers:

- You're using 3 different last row variables for the same sheet? You can overwrite a variable just fine, no need for a 2nd/3rd unless you need to keep them all available for something else.
- You loop with i but then have `Next d`?
- Unused variable dlRow
- Instead of defining a one-value Array (?), loop through the sheets in `wb.Worksheets` and check if the name is like "BT*"

So it could look like this:

```
Sub Overzicht_2()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lRow3 As Long, i As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wtrws As Worksheet
    Dim arrRanges
    
    arrRanges = Array("B11:V170", "B176:V205", "B211:V290")
        
    For Each wtrws In wb.Worksheets
        If wtrws.Name Like "BT*" Then
        'you could also use If Left(wtrws.Name,2) = "BT"
            For i = 0 To UBound(arrRanges)
                wtrws.Range(arrRanges(i)).Copy
                lRow3 = Blad3.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                '+1 so you don't overwrite the last row with data
                Blad3.Range("B" & lRow3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
                    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Next i
        End If
    Next wtrws
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'in case you really need to have this selected, you can leave this part in
    'Blad1.Select
    'Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

If need be, you can check the sheet isn't Blad3 in case they change its name to "BT"-something.